# Control over Animation of Angular Material form-field Label/Placeholder

Tags: angular, angular-material

In context of Angular Material, is there any possibility, we can modify floating label animation of form-field or even define an entirely new animation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the label animation with this CSS class:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-can-float .mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.4em) translateX(1em) scale(.80);
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

While with this class:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-outline-gap{
  margin-right: 4em;
}
```

You can try to change the outline gap (pay attention, in this way it will change not only the top-border but also the bottom one).
I haven't used this classes much, so i'm not sure those are the only class needed for your purpose.
Hope it helps ;)